# How to convert feature time and date into like in 1 hours and 3 minutes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display feature time and date like **in 3 hours and 4 minutes** in Jquery and Javascript, But I didn't get it how to achieve this.

I use `moment.js` and other jquery plugin but it's not working for me. I have date format like `2015-12-3 00:00:00`.

Comment: `moment('2015-11-3 00:00:00').fromNow()` - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/drwy5wom/1/

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
moment('2015/11/3 00:00:00').fromNow()
```

this will work

Comment: But this is only show hours not showing minutes, any idea.